# Setting up postgresql database server in docker container for express api

Tags: postgresql, docker, express, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have an express.js api server application with postgresql as the database that I want to run completely with docker.
This is my project structure:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── Dockerfile
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── routes
│   ├── spending.js
│   └── user.js
├── server.js
└── setup
    ├── config.js
    ├── db.js
    ├── init.sql
    └── middleware.js
```

And here are the relevant files;

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Copy app source
COPY . .

# Expose app port
EXPOSE 3000

# Run sql setup script
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y postgresql-client && \
    /bin/bash -c "psql -h db -U postgres -f setup/init.sql"

# Start app
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "1"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_USER: emirb
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: emir123
      POSTGRES_DB: node
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - node_network
    container_name: db

  api:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - node_network
    container_name: api

networks:
  node_network:
```

init.sql:

```
/* Create user and database for postgresql server */
/* Database table creation will be done in db.js */

-- Create database
CREATE DATABASE node;

-- Create user
CREATE USER db_admin WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'admin123';

-- Grant database privileges
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE node TO db_admin;
```

db.js:

```
const pgPromise = require('pg-promise');

const connectionOptions = {
    host: 'postgres',
    port: 5432,
    database: 'node',
    user: 'emirb',
    password: 'emir123',
};

const pgp = pgPromise();
const db = pgp(connectionOptions);

// database tables are created here

module.exports = db;
```

When I try to create the containers with `docker compose up -d` command I get the following error:

```
psql: error: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

I checked some relevant questions on stackoverflow but couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, host property should be an url or ipAddress, You can try with host: "http://localhost" If your docker container is hosted in your own computer.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem exactly. I changed the host in db.js to localhost and changed this line in the Dockerfile:  `/bin/bash -c "psql -h localhost -U postgres -f setup/init.sql"` 

Now I get this error: `psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused`

I suspect there is something wrong with the docker network connections since localhost is resolved but db is not, but I am not sure what exactly is the problem.